# Wi-Fi not working under Kali

Tags: wireless-networking, kali-linux, usb-storage

I'm running Kali (x64) on a Live USB. Unfortunately, it doesn't detect my integrated Wi-Fi on my laptop (Leapbook M100), and other stuff like battery, the AC to charge the battery and the bluetooth, but at the moment I'd like to focus on the Wi-Fi and will create a different topic for the others once this is fixed/if it's even possible to fix it.

Things I've tried:

- I typed in the terminal "ifconfig". This is what I get:

  [image: ifconfig]
- Interestingly enough, everything on Windows 10 seems to work properly, so I went to System Information and this is what I got from the "Network -> Adaptar" tab:

  [Text file download from mediafire](http://www.mediafire.com/file/y9993wbl07d3gz3/wifi_posting_online.txt)

  I would've posted the text here directly, but it marks it as spam. Probably cause it's too long.
- So, I assumed my Wi-Fi was the Realtek one. There for, I tried `modprobe rtl8192cu` as suggested [here](http://linuxembeded.blogspot.com.es/2014/04/configuring-wifi-module-rtl8188cu.html), but I get nothing once again.

  [image: modprobe]

  But if I  write `modprobe rtl8188cu`, I **do get the fatal error.** Unfortunately, when I tried to access `/boot/config-4.13.0.kali1-amd64`, I get a permission denied error and from what I read [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GTFMB.jpg) I cannot access it since it's on a Live USB.
- I typed `iwconfig` which showed only the following:

  [image: iwconfig]
- I found [this](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2014934) thread on Ubuntu, but unfortunately the link leading to the Realtek website is dead. I checked manualy all of the WLAN pages on Realtek but I couldn't find the appropriate driver.
- I don't see a link to download the `rtl8192cu` on the Linux Wireless drivers page either.
- I typed `lsmod | grep rtl`, which I found in a thread called "[SOLVED] RTL8188CUS Driver Install" whose link I cannot post due reaching maximum number of links (7) (error says "You need at least 10 reputation to post more than 8 links", doesn't look like it includes the 8th), but I couldn't follow the rest of the procedure due to not having any internet (the laptop doesn't have a RJ-45 connector). That shows the following:

  [image: lsmod]

  I did plug in another Wi-Fi USB but it doesn't detect that one either. I know this Wi-Fi works because I can use it on other machines, including other types of Linux, but on the Linux distros it has only ever worked once they were installed, never during Live boot, which is weird. Also, all of my USBs on the laptop work, I've tested.

---

What else can I try? Is the only way to "repair" it to install Kali on the laptop? I'd really like to avoid that. From what I've heard, and especially since I'm no pro in the Linux industry, it's not the brightest idea and that it's better to just boot it live when you need it due to security holes.

---

Edit:
New commands I tried:

`lshw` and `hwinfo` don't work. These packages don't seem to come with the Kali.

`nano /proc/devices` shows: `1 mem`, `4 /dev/vc/0`, `4 tty`, `4 ttyS`, `5 /dev/tty`, `5 /dev/console`, `5 /dev/ptmx`, `7 vcs`, `10 misc`, `13 input`, `21 sg`, `29 fb`, `81 video4linux`, `116 alsa`, `128 ptm`, `136 pts`, `180 usb`, `189 usb_device`, `226 drm`, `247 media`, `248 hidraw`, `249 bsg`, `250 watchdog`, `251 rtc`, `252 dax`, `253 tpm`, `254 gpiochip` and then `Block devices:`, `259 blkext`, `7 loop` and the following numbers are all for `sd`:  `8 65 66 67 68 69 70 71 128 129 130 131 132 133 134 135`, `179 mmc`.

`ls /sys/class/net` only shows `lo` just like the `ifconfig` picture.

`lspci` didn't show anything even remotely similar to wireless things, only `Host bridge` (SoC transaction register), `VGA compatible controller`, `Multimedia controller`, `Signal processing controller` (power management), `USB controller`, `Encryption controller` and `ISA bridge` (PCU).

`nmcli connection show` only shows one line containing the following: `NAME UUID TYPE DEVICE`, but no information under those.

---

Edit2: Thanks to UncertainWhatNameToPickHere, downloading "[kali-linux-2017-W52-amd64.iso](https://cdimage.kali.org/kali-images/kali-weekly/)" from the link provided in his comment (cannot post here due to maximum number of links) and booting it has fixed the issue. My Wi-Fi is working during live boot, but I've not tested if it will still work if I were to install Kali on the laptop.

---

Edit3: The Wi-Fi also works after installing the mentioned Kali Version. ^^

Comment: Don't post thumbnails of screenshots of photos of a screen using your flash. It's totally unreadable. Copy/paste the output here and use preformatted text using `{` and `}` instead.

Comment: @TeunVink It's visible now. I thought putting the "s" at the end only made it smaller on the preview in the post but when clicked upon they'd get bigger, but apparently not. So I've removed the "s".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Downloading the latest Kali Weekly Build https://cdimage.kali.org/kali-images/kali-weekly/  makes a difference.  They're currently at Week52, the last build for 2017 and it would include hardware updates and contributions from the community.

In addition, updates, albeit not always the most recent updates, but updates to the vulnerability signatures like Metasploit are more current inside the weekly builds.

Comment: The Wi-Fi also works after installing the Kali. Just thought you might want to know. ^^

Answer (score 0):

does `nmcli n on` and than `nmcli d wifi` work?
I once had this issue but it still worked, it just wasn't enabled.
`nmcli --ask d wifi connect <WiFi name>` to connect if it works.

Comment: When I typed `nmcli n on` and `nmcli d wifi` there were no messages. Like, I wrote each and pressed `Enter` and went on to the next line, no errors no confirmations, nothing. When I wrote `nmcli --ask d wifi connect <Wifi name>` I got an error saying `Error: No Wi-Fi device found`. The `ifconfig` and `iwconfig` still show the same information as the original pictures posted in the first post.

Answer (score -1):

If you installed and partitioned your USB properly with the correct Kali image, your OS should have no problem utilizing the internal hardware.
With that said, your images are too difficult to read.
I would recommend trying to reinstall Kali Linux onto your USB again following the [steps given](https://docs.kali.org/downloading/kali-linux-live-usb-install). Additionally, make sure that all of your hardware specifications meet or exceed the requirements given.

Comment: My system does meet the requirements and it exceeds them.
I've installed the Kali on the USB as it was shown in the official guide.

Comment: @DoombringerBG To clarify, are you using the latest Kali weekly build ? https://cdimage.kali.org/kali-images/kali-weekly/  Looked up your Leapbook, nice laptop, congratulations. Is it fairly new ? When I've tried the latest laptops with Kali and the days of Backtrack, it took some time for the authors at SecureComputing and the community to "catch up"

Comment: Thank you for the compliment on the laptop, in reality it's a piece of shit. I regret buying it. I bought it in July-August this year. I think it's quite new, but from what I managed to find out a few months ago, all of the parts seem to be from china and japan and don't look like they're new themselves.

I downloaded the x64 version from the official Kali download page. I followed the link you provided and compared the SHA256SUMs and they don't match. Would you recommend trying out the weekly build?

Comment: @UncertainWhatNameToPickHere Just downloaded and booted up the "kali-linux-2017-W52-amd64.iso" version from the link you provided. My Wi-Fi is working.

Comment: @DoombringerBG  I'm glad that worked! I posted an answer with my previous comment and I envy your Kali Leapbook.

Comment: @DoombringerBG Keep in touch, there's a lot of techniques I've learned and devised when pentesting WiFi along with escape and evasion / small unit tactics in group testing, all things I just enjoy talking about anyway and can chat further about in a room.